# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error when authenticating to a web service using X.509

Tags: c#, web-services, certificate, x509certificate, tls1.2

I've seen several threads with the same error and tried various potential solutions, but so far no luck. I am working with a client's REST endpoint, which requires a client certificate to authenticate. I have the certificate and have installed it for the current user and the local machine by double-clicking the .pfx and completing the wizard. I also ran the following using `winhttpcertcfg` so that the app pool identity account (`Network Service`) can use the certificate:

```
winhttpcertcfg -i "<path to .pfx> -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -a "Network Service" -p "<password for .pfx>
```

I've added the certificates snap-in to MMC and added my certificate, so when I hit the API endpoint URL in Chrome, the certificate shows up and I click it, and I see the XML returned.

Unfortunately, the code I am using is encountering an error when trying to get a response. My code (which is within an MVC action):

```
        var url = "https://obfuscated.api.endpoint.host/api/Profile";
        var certPath = @"C:\Users\paldrich\AdvisorDirectoryClient.pfx";
        var xmlResult = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=UTF8";

            X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(certPath, "obfuscated-password");
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            xmlResult = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Bio App web service call failed.", ex, "AdvisorController");
            xmlResult = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(xmlResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

When it tries to get the response (`response.GetResponse()`), I see the following error: `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

Things I've Tried:

- Granting full access for `Network Service` to my certificate under `C:\Users\paldrich`.
- Making the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` just `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` and also just `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`.
- Checking "Mark this key as exportable" in the certificate import wizard for both Current User and Local Machine.
- Verified that I have `Use Tls 1.0`, `Use Tls 1.1` and `Use Tls 1.2` all checked in Internet Properties.

Comment: Are you working on windows? Could you try to enable Capi2 logging in WindowsEvent to see more about the problem?

Comment: I did and it's good to know that. However I realized what my problem was after submitting this. I needed to use `X509Certificate2` instead of `X509Certificate`, although I don't understand why, outside of the fact that `X509Certificate2` is newer.

Comment: You can then post the answer and accept it as you solved it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what my problem was after submitting this. I needed to use `X509Certificate2` instead of `X509Certificate` (I figured this out by just trying 2), although I don't understand why, outside of the fact that X509Certificate2 is newer. Regardless, the XML is coming up; it is showing up as a Unicode converted string, but overall the goal has been accomplished.

So, instead of:

```
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(certPath, "obfuscated-password");
```

I had to use:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "obfuscated-password");
```